# Spring Cloud Stream FencedInstanceIdException

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Can someone who is experienced with spring cloud stream with kafka binder help with clarifying this question?

I have a simple application which consumes from different topics. This is my config and looks correct based on the spring doc.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: app
    stream:
      bindings:
        app-in-0:
          destination: topic-a,topic-b
          group: mygroup
      kafka:
        binder:
          consumer-properties:
            group:
              instance:
                id: myid
```

But I get this error.

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.FencedInstanceIdException: The broker rejected this static consumer since another consumer with the same group.instance.id has registered with a different member.id.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.FencedInstanceIdException: The broker rejected this static consumer since another consumer with the same group.instance.id has registered with a different member.id.
```

It works fine for single topic. Fails only for more than 1 topic. I could guess it happens because spring seems to create 2 different "consumer" for each topic. But not sure how I can fix this in this case?

---

After Gary's answer, I tried this.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: app
    stream:
      bindings:
        app-in-0:
          destination: topic-a,topic-b
          group: mygroup
          consumer:
            multiplex: true
      kafka:
        binder:
          consumer-properties:
            group:
              instance:
                id: myid
```

I get this error.

```
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [topic-a,topic-b]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [topic-a,topic-b]
```

DEBUG mode shows this.

```
Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=consumer-my-group-1, correlationId=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='topic-a,topic-b')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)

Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=12, clientId=consumer-my-group-1, correlationId=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=1, host='localhost', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='OTMwNzFhYTY1ODNiNGE5OQ', controllerId=1, topics=[MetadataResponseTopic(errorCode=17, name='topic-a,topic-b', topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, isInternal=false, partitions=[], topicAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.app-in-0.consumer.multiplex:true`.

```java
/**
 * When set to true, the underlying binder will natively multiplex destinations on the
 * same input binding. For example, in the case of a comma separated multiple
 * destinations, the core framework will skip binding them individually if this is set
 * to true, but delegate that responsibility to the binder.
 *
 * By default this property is set to `false` and the binder will individually bind
 * each destinations in case of a comma separated multi destination list. The
 * individual binder implementations that need to support multiple input bindings
 * natively (multiplex) can enable this property.
 */
private boolean multiplex;
```

**EDIT**

You have the `multiplex` in the wrong place; it is a binding consumer property, not a top level `spring.cloud.stream` property.

This works fine for me.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75912831Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75912831Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> input() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=foo
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.destination=topic1,topic2
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.consumer.multiplex=true
```

```
...o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$2 \
  foo: partitions assigned: [topic1-0, topic2-0]
```

Comment: Sorry to say this - This solution does not work. ` org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [topic-a,topic-b]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [topic-a,topic-b]`

Comment: I think it is a BUG. please check the updated question with log info.

Comment: Your configuration is wrong; see my edit.

Comment: That was my copy-paste mistake in the config when I did in SO. not in the application. Ok.. confirming it is a BUG in the `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive`. Change your consumer to `Flux<String>`

Comment: Multiplex is not currently supported by the (recently added) reactive binder, only by the message channel binder (which should not be used with reactive workloads). Please open a new feature issue on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2691